# Adjust the position of overbrace-text relative to a formula

Tags: math-mode, braces

I have the following design-problem (there's probably a solution, unfortunately I just can't remember anymore):

```
\[ a^2 b^2 + c \overbrace{r \cdot \Underbrace{\eta}_{\equiv 1} \cdot x}^{\shortstack{ \text{variable costs} \rightarrow K = \eta} } a^2 + b^2 + c \]
```

[image]

It should do the following:

- make the brace-text ignore the size of the brace and the underlying formula
- if possible, don't center the brace-text, but left-align it right above the first element of the brace-formula (here *r*)

[image]

Thanks for any suggestions :)

*How about even longer brace-text-formulas?*

Do I have to use tables or tikzpictures?

[image]

The solution (by paint) is very easy to achieve. And there has to be a way within latex. But of course in case there's no *easy* way to modifty the braces, I rather will rewrite my entire text and formulas.

Comment: The `\shortstack` instruction doesn't seem to be doing anything. Can it be omitted?

Comment: Oh yes, I think it can. It's a a relict of another code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution aligned on one line as you want. It relies on the `eqparbox` package. I  define an `\eqmathbox` command, which stores the width of the ‘over/underbraced’ formula with a system of tags, and I use it for another `\eqmakebox` which contains the text, combined with `\rlap` and `\mathclap` at appropriate places. Note the spacing aroud  the `\cdots` is now correct.

For small formulae to be overbracketed, I suggest to use the `\over/underbracket` commands from mathtools, as they look nicer, in my opinion.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \mathclap macro; calls 'amsmath' automatically
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand\eqmathbox[1]{\eqmakebox[M]{$\displaystyle #1$}}
\begin{document}

\[
a^2 b^2 + c
\overbracket[0.5pt]{\eqmathbox{\mathstrut r \cdot\! {\underbracket[0.5pt]{\,\eta\,}_{\mathclap{\equiv 1}}}\! \cdot x}}^{
\eqmakebox[M][l]{\rlap{variable costs $ \rightarrow K = \eta $}}}
a^2 + b^2 + c
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Rather than let the material above the overbrace dangle out to the right, I'd introduce a line break in the overbrace material, and I'd enclose the two-line material in a `\mathclap` wrapper so that it's allowed to stick out to both the left and the right, if necessary.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \mathclap macro; calls 'amsmath' automatically
\begin{document}

\[ 
a^2 b^2 + c 
\overbrace{r \cdot {\underbrace{\eta}_{\equiv 1}} \cdot x}^{
\mathclap{\substack{\text{variable costs }\\[0.75ex] 
                    \rightarrow K = \eta}}} 
a^2 + b^2 + c 
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: For my special purpose, a two-line solution isn't that suitable. I often need to deal with even longer issues.